# Laravel 4 Array of Std Objects to view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

This is my first question in SO trying to explain as much as I can.

I am creating a report using stored procedure in mysql. I am getting array of std objects using laravel4 in the format below. I can get this working fine

```
    Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [date] => 2015-08-01
            [Tuition Fee] => 1000
            [Hostel] => 500
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [date] => 2015-10-01
            [Tuition Fee] => 1500
            [Hostel] => 
        )

)
```

I want to convert it to an HTML Table. I can do that using foreach loop

```
date       | Tuition Fee | Hostel
2015-08-01 | 1000        | 500
2015-10-01 | 1500        |
```

Code in view:

```
    @foreach($x as $user) 
 {{ $user->date}}
{{ $user->Tuition Fee }}
@endforeach
```

However the table doesnt have fixed column heading. It could be 5 colummns or 7 columns depending on report. eg-

```
dateToCharge | Tuition Fee | Miscalleneous Fee | Development Fee
```

Please help in this regards as I have been banging my head for last 10 days.

Comment: so you want to show the data's dynamically?

Comment: yes aldrin. I want to display headings and rest of the date dynamically

Comment: Can you show me the code where did you get the data?

Comment: In my controller I am calling $oldData = DB::select('CALL Pivot(?)',array($id));

My procedure is:
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'sum(CASE WHEN feecategory_id = ',
      feecategory_id,
      ' THEN amount END) AS `',
      fee_category.Category, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM fee_planner f 
LEFT JOIN fee_category ON (f.feecategory_id=fee_category.id)
where f.std_id=@id;

SET @sql 
  = CONCAT('SELECT dateToCharge, ', @sql, ' 
           FROM fee_planner 
            GROUP BY dateToCharge');

Comment: Is `$oldData` variable in your controller equals to the `$x` variable in view?

Comment: yes aldrin $oldData is equal to $x in view

Comment: Can you try my updated answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to generate the column headings dynamically, you could try doing the following:

1. First of all, you need to convert the *objects* into `arrays` (using [`get_object_vars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) method in your php code):

   ```
   $users = array();
   foreach($x as $user){
        $users[] = get_object_vars($user);
   }
   ```

   after which you'll have your previous objects in the following array format:

   ```
   [0] => array(3) { 
       ['date'] => '2015-08-01'
       ['Tuition Fee'] => 1000
       ['Hostel'] => 500
   }
   ```
2. *Extract* the columns into a separate array (*named `columns` here*):

   ```
   $columns = array();
      foreach($users as $user){
           foreach($user as $column => $value){
               $columns[] = $column;
      }
      break; //since we'd want to loop only once to get the column names
   }
   ```
3. In your view, iterate the `columns` array and `users` array to get the desired resulting table.

   ```
   <table>
     <thead>
       <tr>
           @foreach($columns as $column)
               <th>{{ $column }}</th>
           @endforeach
       </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
       @foreach($users as $user)
           <tr>    
               @foreach($columns as $column)             
                    <td>{{ $user[$column] }}</td>
               @endforeach
           </tr>
       @endforeach
     </tbody>
   </table>
   ```

Comment: Thanks for detailed description +1 for that. A small edit here for readers of this post. Please put $user[$column] in double curly braces to echo in laravel {{

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

In your view:

```
@foreach($x as $key => $user)
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>{{$key}}</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>{{$user}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Aldrin. I have been doing this. But I am looking for a generalised statement like 
{{$user->[$key]}}
Because date, tuitionfee, hostel are not constant. These could be 5 or 6 depending on report. Headings are dynamic

Comment: I've updated my answer @Natasha. Maybe this should work because I make every key and value to be dynamically input in the table.

Comment: Thanks man. it does start looping but still not getting result.